# Emacs: show helm-buffers-list in a specific window

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I normally split my Emacs into two windows. One of them(A) is for text file, the other(B) is for everything else, like *shell*, *scratch*. When I call (helm-buffers-list), which invokes the buffer named *helm buffers*, I want to show it in window B always.

As an example, I have two windows now:

```
(window-list)
(#<window 6 on *scratch*> #<window 1 on Csv.h>)
```

If I try to control where to show the helm buffer list,

```
(defun helm-buffer (buffer alist)
  (set-window-buffer
   (nth 0 (window-list)) ; Changing 0 to 1 makes no difference 
   buffer))  
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist (cons ".*helm.*" (cons #'helm-buffer nil)))
```

Looks like it has no effect to to helm at all.

Any idea on how to control which window to show helm buffer list?

***Versions***
Ubuntu 14.04, emacs 24.5.1, Helm is a master clone days ago